# How do I fix the "This app is blocked" error message in ShareGate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, google-workspace

I'm configuring ShareGate migration tool for Google workspace to OneDrive migration. But I'm getting the below error while connecting to Google workspace.

**Error:**
[image]

I have added ShareGate as a trusted app in Google admin as per this documentation (https://documentation.sharegate.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037473391-Add-ShareGate-Desktop-to-the-G-Suite-whitelist-for-Google-Drive-migrations?utm_source=Sharegate&utm_medium=App&utm_campaign=App-Support)

Kindly Suggest how this can be mitigated !!